# border overlapping with empty thead and border-collapse in safari and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, border

In chrome and safari browsers, the border of a td overlaps the previous element when there's an empty thead and border-collapse: collapse;

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 25px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In chrome or safari the Text "Hello", shown in the div before the table, is not readable because of the overlapping border from the td. But it's shown well in firefox.

In Safari an Chrome the border is not overlapping the text in the following cases:

- without an empty thead
- without the border-collapse
- with a th in the thead

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Seems to be wrong in chrome or safari or does anyone knows if there is a reason for the different behaviors?

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does look like a flaw in Chrome's display engine, yes.
There is, however, a simple workaround: just add `thead:empty {display:none}` to the stylesheet.

```css
thead:empty {display:none}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>Hello</div>
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>Hello</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: 15px solid black">World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes thanks:  display: none for the empty thead works in all browser

Comment: OK. If this answers the question, could you mark it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left? Then this will no longer show up under unsolved questions.

Comment: display: none is just a workaround. But if it is really a flaw in safari and chrome, than it's the answer, too.